# In Hide/Show expression, can I specify a subset of a data set? Or only the data set

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

Trying to run an iif expression to see if something is the last row, then to display a field.  However, it isn't working correctly, because I need to check if it is the last row a specific order.  The dataset has information for several orders.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you tried but doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

The Last() function sounds like exactly what you want.  However, for it to work the way you want, you need to have a sort order applied to the scope you're looking at.  For example, the Detail group of your tablix control.

Last() is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283113(v=sql.105).aspx

A sample expression might be:

```
=Iif(Last(myData.OrderId.Value) = myData.OrderId.Value, True, False)
```